# Comprobar si fue abierta en PWA

Tags: javascript, html, pwa

Querría saber como podría comprobar si el usuario entró en modo PWA o en la web.

Intenté usar el

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches || window.navigator.standalone === true) {

      //Entro con PWA

}
```

Per al parecer ser que en Android no me funciona. No detecta bien lo de `standalone`.

No se si es porque en mi `manifest.json` puse en display como fullscreen `"display": "fullscreen"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para detectar si el usuario abrió la aplicación en modo PWA debes utilizar el mismo valor en la función `window.matchMedia` que usaste en el manifiesto de la aplicación. Si no, estos no coinciden y devolverá el valor `false`.

El código quedaría así:

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').matches) {

      // Entró con PWA

}
```

La propiedad `window.navigator.standalone` no es estándar, por lo que se devería evitar utilizar.